# underscorejs groupby and filter

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array of objects. I would like to `groupby` & `filter(remove)` the object, category which is undefined. Please refer the script below for more clarity :

```
arrayFlatten = [
      {
        area:"Digital",
        category:undefined,
        qId:"q11",
        qqId:"step1",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:1,
        userId:1,
        weightedAverage:0
      },
      {
        area:"Digital",
        category:"Analytics",
        qId:"q1",
        qqId:"step1",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:1,
        userId:1,
        weightedAverage:0
      },
      {
        area:"Digital",
        category:"Analytics",
        qId:"q1",
        qqId:"step2",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:1,
        userId:1,
        weightedAverage:0
      }
]
```

The command used to sort using group by

```
var groupCategory = _.groupBy(arrayFlatten,'category');
console.log(groupCategory);
```

The expected result is supposed to look like:

```
arrayFlatten = [
          {
            area:"Digital",
            category:"Analytics",
            qId:"q1",
            qqId:"step1",
            type:"Reduce",
            val:1,
            userId:1,
            weightedAverage:0
          },
          {
            area:"Digital",
            category:"Analytics",
            qId:"q1",
            qqId:"step2",
            type:"Reduce",
            val:1,
            userId:1,
            weightedAverage:0
          }
    ]
```

Comment: Do you actually need to do any grouping here, or just filter out items with a category of undefined?

Comment: I need filter out the items with a category of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filteredArray = _.filter(
    arrayFlatten,
    function (obj) {
        return obj.category !== undefined;
    }
);
```

`filteredArray` will contain your array with no undefined categories.

You can also do this without underscore in most modern browsers, using `Array.filter()` described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thanks @Simon. Could you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273546/count-category-by-userid-using-underscorejs . 

Do the needful